# Python: ValueError only happening on AppEngine but works fine local

Tags: python, google-app-engine, int

This is strange. Run the code and it works fine on local server but when uploading it to app engine it doesn't work at all and gets the error:

```
    if int(totaltime[0:2]) == 23 and int(totaltime[3:5]) >= 45:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ', '
```

Here is the code that is triggering it:

```
        if int(totaltime[0:2]) == 23 and int(totaltime[3:5]) >= 45:
            ta = "yes"
        else:
            ta = "no"
```

totaltime is 23:27:35 so int(totaltime[0:2]) gets 23 and (totaltime[3:5]) gets 27.
I don't understand why this doesn't work online but works fine local.

Comment: And how do you construct the totaltime?

Comment: It's a datetime. I copy the datetime to a string, separate the date to a string and the time to a string (timetotal)

Answer (score 2):

The exception says that your input data contains a comma, so your expectation of `totaltime` being `23:27:35` is clearly violated.

Try outputting `repr(totaltime[0:2])` and `repr(totaltime[3:5])` on Appengine.

Also, you can split the if-statement into two lines like so:

```
if (int(totaltime[0:2]) == 23 and 
    int(totaltime[3:5]) >= 45):
```

That will let you see which of the calls to `int()` triggers the `ValueError`, making debugging a bit easier.

Also be aware that date strings (both from `time` and `datetime` honor the locale settings, which may explain the discrepancy between your development system and AppEngine.

Comment: if (int(totaltime[0:2]) == 23 and
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ', '

datetime is from a list not related to local time.

Comment: What do the repr() statements give you? As I said, I suspect the strings look different on GAE than they do on your dev machine. Knowing what they _do_ look like is the first step in fixing the code.